# Can someone please explain the work of a resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, work, electrical-resistance, conductors

Well I want to know what does a resistor do let our electrical appliances from burning in a circuit I know it does not slow the current flow so what does it really do?

Comment: Resistor and current have the same relation as traffic and speed of a car. (taking the voltage to be constant). :)

Comment: For clarity, please stick to correct grammar and punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

A resistor does 'slow' or reduces the current.

For example, if a $12$ V battery is in a circuit with a $2 \ \Omega$  resistor, the current is calculated from

$\text{Voltage} = \text{current} \times \text{resistance}$.

Current $= 12/2 = 6$ Amp.

If the resistance was doubled to $4 \ \Omega$, the current would then be $12/4 = 3$ Amps.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really do anything...when you show a resistor in a circuit you are actually representing the resistance to the flow of current of your load i.e. some device that would be connected like say a toaster. But we do use resistors to make more accurate ammeters and voltmeters for DC current. To make an ammeter using a galvanometer and resistor we connect a low resistance resistor called a shunt in parallel with the galvanometer and to make a voltmeter, we connect the shunt (having very high resistance) in series with the galvanometer, which in turn is connected in parallel to the device under analysis. If you want to know more about how they work you can google it.[image: SOURCE : My notes]

[image: SOURCE : My notes]